# Ouptut options ignored when using 'render_book' ('preamble'.tex' ignored)

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm having some trouble to compile an entire document from many Rmd files by using the bookdown approach.

If I knit individual .Rmd files then 'preamble.tex' included in YAML options is taken into account.

If I render the book ([with both approaches described here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html)), then 'preamble.tex' is ignored.

To make things concrete, consider the following mwe:

**preamble.tex:**

```
\usepackage{times}
```

**index.Rmd:**

```
---
title: "My paper"

site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"

output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"
---
```

**01-intro.Rmd:**

```
# Introduction

This chapter is an overview of the methods that we propose to solve an **important problem**.
```

Then, by knitting 'index.Rmd' or '01-intro.Rmd' the font indicated in 'preamble.tex' is used.

However when rendering with `bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd',"bookdown::pdf_book", new_session = T)` it is simply ignored.

What is more, in my actual project there are other output options that end up ignored. For example, I use `toc: false` and it works when knitting single files, but fails when rendering the document.

In this simple example it would be okay to use a single file, but my actual project has many chapters with R chunks within each of them. Thus, building a single file doesn't seem a good idea.

I appreciate any hints on what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing here is that in your YAML header, `preamble.tex` is included for the `bookdown::pdf_document2` output format and not `bookdown::pdf_book`, the format you pass to the `output_format` argument in `bookdown::render_book()`. For this reason, other YAML options (like `toc: true`) do not work either.

Running

`bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', "bookdown::pdf_document2", new_session = T)`

instead should work.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, confusingly,  `bookdown::render_book(format="bookdown::pdf_book")` makes use of the output yml info, while it is ignored with `bookdown::render_book(format=bookdown::pdf_book())`